# textarea blurs when clicking inside

Tags: javascript, html, onblur

I have a field in an HTML table in which the user can edit the values. When the user clicks one of the cells of that field, a textarea appears at this cell, the user edits whatever he wants and when he clicks outside of that textarea, it goes back to normal text. You know, standard stuff.

[image: textarea editor]

All of this is working properly with *onfocus* and *onblur* events, except for one thing : when I click **inside** the textarea (Ex.: I want to edit a certain part of the text by clicking between two letters), the **onblur** event is still called, thus closing the textarea, which is not what I want.

I'm having a hard time understanding why the event is called. Is this the phenomenon called *event propagation* I heard about? How can I work around or fix this behaviour?

Here's my code related to the situation (lightened a bit) :

Javascript

```
// Create a function that updates a table cell once the textarea loses focus (do not be confused with "losing its Ford Focus")
function createBlurFunction( cell, textArea, functionName ) {
    return function() {

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                var result = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText)[0];

                /* Do stuff with AJAX result */
            }
        }

        // Empty cell
        cell.innerHTML = "";

        // Send AJAX request
        xmlhttp.open("GET","Some AJAX parameters", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}

// textArea is already defined somewhere else
textArea.addEventListener('blur', createBlurFunction( cell, textArea, cell.title ), false);
```

Thanks!

**EDIT 1 :**

I used a similar structure somewhere else in my web page (textarea that goes away when you click outside) and the behaviour is different : the textarea does not go away when I click inside of it.

However, I used Copy/Paste from the code above, so I might be suspecting a code error or something...

Comment: I don't know if it's the issue, but on the last line have you tried putting the listener on the `onblur` event instead of just `blur` ?

Comment: The addEventListener does not need the "on" to the event name parameter ;)

Comment: My bad, I'm trying to figure what's going wrong. have you tried putting some `alert()` or `console.log()` in those functions to check when they were executed? You could try to find where those *unwanted* event firing originate from, this way.

Comment: I'm guessing that the behaviour here is similar to this : http://jsfiddle.net/37z6b/

Answer (score 1):

You could put the blur function on a timeout and in your focus listener clear the timeout.

```
var timer;
function createBlurFunction() {
    var myFunc = function() { ... }
    return function() {timer = setTimeout(myFunc(),300);};
}

function myFocusFunction() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand how that would help :/

Comment: Oh, is the issue not that the blur event is triggered upon clicking within the textarea even though you're still focusing on it? This would only close the textarea if you then didn't refocus on it afterwards. Sorry if I misunderstood your issue!

Comment: No that exactly the issue, I just wasn't sure I fully understood your code. If I'm not mistaken, your thing is that the blur creates a timer that is cancelled if the focus is kept?

Comment: Right. This essentially delays the closing of the text area until you know if they actually meant to click away from it or just clicked inside it. I believe it should do the trick. If it doesn't you could also try clearing the timeout on click of the text as well.

Comment: That doesn't solve the root of the problem, but if I can't find any solution I think this would be a good fix. Thanks!